# Storing a function pointer as a member within a class

Tags: c++, windows, class, winapi, pointers

I created this account to ask a question because I'm pretty lost right now and I couldn't find an answer. I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is even possible, or perhaps I'm taking an incorrect approach.

I'm writing a windows socket wrapper class for asynchronous sockets, mostly so I never have to write this code again, and I'm trying to store a function pointer as a member variable inside my netcode class that points to a windows event handler that's called inside the application's normal win32 message pump that points elsewhere. Basically, I'm trying to create a programmer-defined callback function so that when I compile this netcode class into a .dll I never have to touch it again.

As a clarification, what I'm trying to do is, for example, write the event handler for `WM_SOCKET` (which is a windows message I have defined) somewhere other than inside the network code class (so it can be portable to different win32/C++ projects) and outside of the main win32 message pump (so my `WndProc()` doesn't become absolutely massive).

I don't even know what to search for, but all of the information I'm finding is about creating a pointer to a member function or a member of a template, which isn't what I want.

Here's the code I've already tried to write (only the relevant bits), which is what is giving me problems. I'm probably royally screwing something up here.

```
//// Sockets.h
class NetworkConnection
{
private:
    void (*WMSocketFunction)(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

public:
    void HandleEvents(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
    void registerSocketFunction( void (*SocketFunction(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)));
};

//// Sockets.cpp
#include "Sockets.h"

void NetworkConnection::registerSocketFunction( void (*SocketFunction(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)))
{
    WMSocketFunction = SocketFunction;
};

void NetworkConnection::HandleEvents(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    WMSocketFunction(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
}

//// Application.cpp
void SocketEventHandler(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    // Do socket stuff here
};

int SetupApp()
{
    NetworkConnection NetConnection;
    NetConnection.registerSocketFunction(&SocketEventHandler);
    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK d3d::WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch( msg )
    {

    case WM_SOCKET:
        {
            NetConnection.HandleEvents(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
            break;
        }

    case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            ReleaseDevices();
            break;
        }
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        {
#ifdef _DEBUG
            if (lParam == VK_ESCAPE)
                PostQuitMessage(0);
#endif
        }
    }
    return ::DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

I'd be really grateful for some help, here. I totally have no clue why this isn't working.

The errors I receive are:

```
Error   1   error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'void *(__cdecl *)(HWND,UINT,WPARAM,LPARAM)' to 'void (__cdecl *)(HWND,UINT,WPARAM,LPARAM)'    sockets.cpp (in function registerSocketFunction)
Error   2   error C2275: 'HWND' : illegal use of this type as an expression     sockets.cpp (in function HandleEvents)
Error   3   error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'hwnd'    sockets.cpp (in function HandleEvents)
Error   4   error C2059: syntax error : ')'    sockets.cpp (in function HandleEvents)
Error   8   error C2664: 'NetworkConnection::registerSocketFunction' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'void (__cdecl *)(HWND,UINT,WPARAM,LPARAM)' to 'void *(__cdecl *)(HWND,UINT,WPARAM,LPARAM)'    application.cpp
```

If you need any better explanation, because I've likely explained this problem poorly, please don't hesitate to ask.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010, so I don't think I can use C++/11 features like std::function.

Comment: Can you explain why you included the C tag?

Comment: It was one of the suggested tags. Let me fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to enclose the function pointer name in brackets like this: `void (*SocketFunction)(...)`
So instead of your method declaration:

```
void registerSocketFunction( void (*SocketFunction(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)));
```

You have to write:

```
void registerSocketFunction( void (*SocketFunction)(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam));
```

Also rewrite your method body to this:

```
void NetworkConnection::registerSocketFunction( void (*SocketFunction)(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM))
{
    WMSocketFunction = SocketFunction;
};
```

Next thing, i think your HandleEvents is unfinished yet, you have a syntax error there, i think you wanted to call the function behind the pointer.

```
void NetworkConnection::HandleEvents(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    WMSocketFunction(hwnd,msg,wParam,lParam);
}
```

Comment: Oh, my. That did it! Edit: Hit enter prematurely. Thank you very much for catching my mistakes! I'd vote you up if I had the reputation to do it. I was about to throw it out and try a different approach,

Comment: Shouldn't calling the function via pointer look like `(*WMSocketFunction)(hwnd,msg,wParam,lParam);`?

Comment: @g-makulik It will work both ways. I think that my way reads just cleaner.

Answer (score 4):

1. Exclude arguments names from function pointer declaration
2. Use typedef to make code cleaner

   ```
   typedef void(*WMSocketFunction_Ptr)(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

   class NetworkConnection
   {
   private:
       WMSocketFunction_Ptr WMSocketFunction;

   public:
       void HandleEvents(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
       void registerSocketFunction(WMSocketFunction_Ptr SocketFunction);
   };

   void NetworkConnection::registerSocketFunction(WMSocketFunction_Ptr SocketFunction)
   {
       WMSocketFunction = SocketFunction;
   };
   ```
3. Prefer to use STL facilities to naked pointers: [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) of [boost::function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/function.html)

   ```
   typedef std::function<void(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)> WMSocketFunction_Ptr;
   ```

Comment: If I may ask, are there any benefits to using STL facilities in this example? What would the syntax be? EDIT: Also, I don't think I can use that, since Visual Studio 2010 lacks good C++/11 support, right?

Comment: std::function more readable, more typesafe and therefore less error-prone. But main benefit, it is more flexible: it allows you to bind not only functions, but std::bind expressions, function objects and lambdas. If I remember correct, VS2010 with some service pack supports `std::tr1::function`. If your compiler not supports it, you can use boost::function.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suspicion. I think the way you've declared the function argument `SocketFunction` for `registerSocketFunction` is wrong.

```
void NetworkConnection::registerSocketFunction( void (*SocketFunction(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)))
```

should be,

```
void NetworkConnection::registerSocketFunction( void (*SocketFunction)(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam))
```

I ran a similar test on GCC, and it threw a similar error, so this might be your problem.